# Writing a custom NER and POS tagger in pyspark to use in the pipeline method for feature extraction of textual inputs

Tags: nlp, pyspark, feature-extraction

I am doing a text classification project and I am using the pipeline method from mllib to chain the feature extraction stages. My dataset consists of English sentences. I have the Tokenizer and the TFIDF Vectorizer libraries from mllib that I can directly use in the pipeline.

But as a part of the feature extraction process, I also need to extract POS tags and NER tags. Pyspark doesn't have a library for it and I don't know how can I write a custom transformer for NER and POS tagging. I am very new to Spark and Python. I am using Spark 1.6 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
class POSWordTagger(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, stopwords=None):
        super(POSWordTagger, self).__init__()
        self.stopwords = Param(self, "stopwords", "")
        self._setDefault(stopwords=set())
        kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)


    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, stopwords=None):
        kwargs = self.setParams._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)


    def setStopwords(self, value):
        self._paramMap[self.stopwords] = value
        return self

    def getStopwords(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.stopwords)

    def _transform(self, dataset):

        def f(s):
        tokens = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(s)
        pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        return pos_tags

        t = ArrayType(StringType())
        out_col = self.getOutputCol()
        in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]
        return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(f, t)(in_col))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. I also got the idea for how to proceed to do NER. Thanks a lot!